# Pentagonal histogram possible in matplotlib/seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

If I had a 1D histogram with 5 bins, is it all possible via seaborn/matplotlib to make a meaningful histogram that takes the pentagonal shape you see in personality tests like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpfRi.png)?

Comment: That type of plot is called a "radar chart".  That may help you to search for info.  For instance, there is a [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html).

Comment: This is also known under the name "spider chart" or "spider diagram".